# django app on server: apache runs with python 2.7 instead of python 3.5

Tags: python, django, apache, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a Django app on my ubuntu server. Up to now, I was using python 2.7.

My Django version is 1.11.6.

From now on, I want to use python 3.5. But when I run `sudo service apache2 restart` I get errors containing `python 2.7`:

```
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500064 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434] mod_wsgi (pid=28615): Target WSGI script '/home/zinonas/guardianangel/GuardianAngel/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500102 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434] mod_wsgi (pid=28615): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/zinonas/guardianangel/GuardianAngel/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500125 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500144 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]   File "/home/zinonas/guardianangel/GuardianAngel/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500203 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500213 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500240 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500250 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500281 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500308 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500371 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500381 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500393 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500398 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500406 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500411 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500443 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434]     __import__(name)
[Mon Oct 23 12:40:53.500466 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28615] [client 194.42.16.145:23434] ImportError: No module named settings.mysql
```

Do you have any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you installed the libapache2-mod-wsgi package, which is for python 2.

For python 3, you need install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 instead, then apache will use python3.